# How to extract formatted cells and their corresponding rows in Excel

Tags: excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

SO, my problem is as follows:

Using this script written below, I have successfully formatted certain cells in the extracted excel sheet. It is intended to accept any excel file as long as it is entered correctly and is in the same format (which for my purposes will always be in the same format).

My next step (my problem): is how to I grab the cells that have been formatted and their corresponding rows, and then print those rows into a new file.

Using a very similar program I am able to take the chosen formatted excel file.
But do not know what my course

```
def ready():

    print("Type the name of the excel file you wish to analyze.")

    while True:
        try:
            a_input = input(">> ")

            df = pd.read_excel("{}".format(a_input), parse_cols = "AS")

            df2 = pd.read_excel("{}".format(a_input), parse_cols = "B")

            df3 = pd.read_excel("{}".format(a_input), parse_cols = "A")

            df4 = pd.read_excel("{}".format(a_input), parse_cols = "D")

            df5 = pd.read_excel("{}".format(a_input), parse_cols = "C")

        except IOError:
            print("The file name was either entered incorrectly or is not in the directory")

        else:
            print("--------------------File Grab Successful--------------------")
            break

    time.sleep(2)

    print("Grabbing the required data.....\n\n")

    df.set_index('Last Date of Support', inplace=True)

    df2.set_index('Product Series', inplace=True)

    df3.set_index('Product Family', inplace=True)

    df4.set_index('Item Name', inplace=True)

    df5.set_index('Item Type', inplace=True)

    time.sleep(2)

    print("--------------Creating Excel Document with required data------------------\n\n")

    time.sleep(2)

    print("Type the name you want for the excel file that will be created. Be sure to add the file extension on the end (EX: filename.xlsx)")

    b_input = input(">> ")

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('{}'.format(b_input), engine='xlsxwriter')

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=-1, startcol=0)

    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=-1, startcol=4)

    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=-1, startcol=2)

    df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=-1, startcol=3)

    df5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=-1, startcol=1)

    workbook = writer.book

    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

    date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d")

    format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                                   'font_color': '#9C0006'})

    worksheet.conditional_format('A2:A20000', {'type': 'date',
                                              'criteria': 'less than',
                                              'value':  date,
                                              'format': format1})

    writer.save()

    print("Goodbye!")

    time.sleep(5)

ready()
```

Using a very similar program I am able to take the chosen formatted excel file.
But do not know what my course of action would be. 
Here is an example of what I have tried.

```
 format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                                   'font_color': '#9C0006'})

    for i in df == format1:
        print(i)
```

But i keep getting an error.

Sorry for the edit post,
I clicked advance before completed.

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: i is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop you wrote is incorrect. That's because `df==format1` is equivalent to the boolean `True`. If you want to print `i` only when some condition holds, do:

```
upperBound = 1000
for i in range(upperBound):
    if df==format1:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Unfortuantely this is still incorrect as the error I am receiving now is: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Format

Comment: in which line? because in the code you posted you don't call the `int()` function.

Comment: The type error specifies the error on the loop . AKA traces back to that line

Comment: which line exactly